# How I can compare view based NSTableView's cell value with another cell in Swift?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, colors, nstableview

I have made bindings using IB, and in my view-based NSTableView i have two columns, `First` and `Second` which have both integer values. I need be able to compare them, so I can change their text color so it is easier to read.

I have subclassed both like that (except another is `FirstColumn`:

```
import Cocoa

class SecondColumn: NSTableCellView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Here I Can change text color
        self.textField?.textColor = NSColor.redColor()

        // But I want be able to compare that textField value to my first column's value

    }
}
```

I want to have only that second column's text to be red if it's value is smaller than first columns value. So i have tried to make IBOutlet to my `SecondColumn` class like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstColumn: FirstColumn!
```

And then there is error message that says I can't do that. So I wan't do something like this:

```
var secondValue = self.textField?.integerValue
var firstValue = // I don't know how i can get that?? 

if firstValue > secondValue {
        self.textField?.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
    } else {
        self.textField?.textColor = NSColor.greenColor()
    }
```

So how I can do that and is there anyway to do it in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the bindings of the `NSTableView`? Are you using bindings for the text field in the cell view, too? If so, what bindings?

In general, the table view should be bound to an array controller's `arrangedObjects` with no model key path. That is, each row of the table view should represent an object from the array, as a whole. Then, each `NSTableCellView`'s `objectValue` will be that object, again as a whole. The subviews within the cell view, such as the text field, would be bound to the cell view with a model key path that goes through `objectValue` to some specific property of the object.

Given this, every cell view has access to all of the properties of the object represented by the row. It has its `objectValue` property, which is that object. So, the cell view doesn't have to consult its subviews or its sibling cell views to get values for the object. It just has to use its `objectValue`.

So, you could do something like (Objective-C):

```
MyModelClass* model = self.objectValue;
if (model.firstProperty < model.secondProperty)
    self.textField.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
else
    self.textField.textColor = [NSColor greenColor];
```

If you want to do this within IB, then you would need to bind the text field's Text Color binding to the cell view, model key path `objectValue`. Then, you would create a value transformer class (subclass of `NSValueTransformer`) that transforms the model object to a color, basically by comparing the two properties. You'd configure the binding to use that value transformer.

Alternatively, you could implement a property on your `SecondColumn` class that returns the color based on the `objectValue` and you could bind to that. You wouldn't need a value transformer in that case. You would need to implement the proper method to let KVO/bindings know that the color property depends on the key paths "objectValue.firstProperty" and "objectValue.secondProperty". That would be something of the form `+keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>`.

For this simple case, it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I have an ArrayController which is binded (or bounded?) to ManagedObjectContext and it gets its data from Entity. My tableview is bounded to ArrayController and so on. It works fine and shows right data (In real app, i have more complex data than in my example, but same problem)

Comment: And I use bindings for the text field cell view also.

Comment: I figure it out, it was easy solution with that objectValue and I hope that solution is correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, with that objectValue that was quite easy. I made only one subclass of `NSTableCellView` and get needed values from there. So example, lets say I have Entity `Person` with attributes `bankAccount` and `cash` and I have bounded ArrayController to managedObjectContext and to NSTableView etc. My class look like this:

```
        // Drawing code here.
        var obj = self.objectValue as Person
        var bankA = obj.bankAccount
        var sumOfCash = obj.cash

        if Double(bankA) > Double(sumOfCash) {
            self.textField?.textColor = NSColor.greenColor()
        } else {
            self.textField?.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
        }
```